# TcpClient doesn't receive bytes from server

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, networking

**FIXED PROBLEM: client didn't receive any bytes from server because it had to be added to the firewall exception list.**

I have a working server-client connection, the client can send bytes to the server, and server can read it. the problem is that the client doesn't receive any bytes from the server itself.
I'm very new to network programming, please don't be harsh on me.

**Send bytes to client**

```
try
{
    byte[] buff = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("message from server - " + 
    new Random().Next(8000) + "\n");

    NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
    ns.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
}
catch(Exception r) 
{ 
    richTextBox1.AppendText("Sending data to - " + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint + "\n" + r.Message);
}
```

**Receive bytes from server**

```
while(true)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] buff = new byte[1000];
        NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
        ns.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);

        string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buff);
        BackThread.ReportProgress(0, s);
    }
    catch(Exception r) 
    { 
        richTextBox1.AppendText("Failed to get data from server\n" + r.Message + "\n"); 
     }
}
```

Sometimes client gets WsaCancelBlockingCall Exception when tries to receive bytes from the server.

Comment: i suspect some piece of code you are not showing is closing the connection

Comment: You should not edit your question to post an answer.  You can post and accept a real answer to your own question instead.  See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: One of the most common "new to TCP programming" errors is to ignore the return value from `Read` (or moral equivalent function calls). That tells you *how many bytes* have been supplied into your buffer. And could be as low as *1*. It's not guaranteed to match the number of bytes which were supplied by a call to `Write` at the other end - TCP is a stream of bytes, *not* discrete messages.

Comment: I dont need that exact number of bytes that sent from the client, i need specific max byte lengh to avoid overflow